# React Routing in web development using an index template

Tags: reactjs, web, url-routing

Having trouble with my react routing where the site just displays a blank white screen. Anyone who can help??[Code snippet of my home page using the router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIoQi.png)

Tried redownloading the npm react-router-dom and checking all the imports and renders are okay

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What might you require further. Here is the github link for the code
https://github.com/JCOCHARLIE/Shareplay-spotify